# I don't seem to be able to join a IRC network

Tags: c#, .net, irc

I seem to be unable to connect to IRC channels on, for example, the esper IRC network. The program tries to connect to network itself, but it hangs. This is using the [IRC.NET library](https://ircdotnet.codeplex.com/), although I would not be adverse to changing if there is better options.

Here's the code that I use:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using IrcDotNet;

namespace IRCBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IrcClient client = new IrcClient();
            client.Connect("irc.esper.net", 5555, true, new IrcServiceRegistrationInfo { NickName = "SomeBot", Description = "Some Service"});
            ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            client.Connected += (s, e) => mre.Set();
            mre.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine(client.IsConnected);
            client.Channels.Join("test");
            Console.WriteLine(client.Channels[0].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what this could be? Am I just missing something obvious in the IRC protocol? I don't know much about it so I would appreciate any input.

The desired output is that it connects to the IRC network.

Comment: does the library have some sort of support forum? which library are you using? are you getting any exceptions, errors?? can you provide any more information on troubleshooting? what if you use another client, is it working there ...?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair They have an IRC channel, which after 2 days of staying on, didn't have a single person chatting nor a single reply to my question. I am using the IRC.NET library, as stated just before the code. No exceptions/errors, just a hang.

Comment: Of course it hangs! That is what your code is saying with its MRE object: "wait until a connection is made". You should listen to the `ConnectFailed` event on the `client` object. Also listen to `Error` and `ErrorMessageReceived` while you are at it.

Comment: @JeanHominal After hooking up a method to log it if the ConnectFailed and Error and ErrorMessageRecieved, still nothing.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @It'sNotALie: I do not know... Look at the network packets in WireShark? Try using ChatSharp or SmartIrc4net?

Comment: @JeanHominal thanks for tipping me off about ChatSharp... it seems to WORK!